# Reinserting elements causing havoc with my auto increment field

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has the following set of records:

```
Sno Unique  Something
1      1    some data
1      2
1      3
1      4
2      1
2      2
2      3
```

I have achieved this by setting sno and unique_no as a primary key and unique_no being a auto incrementing field. Now the problem is if I delete a field with sno 1 and unique field having the value 1,2,3 and then insert  some other data with sno as 1 this is the kind of table I get:

```
   Sno Unique  Something
    1      5   new data
    1      6   new data
    1      4   somedata
    2      1
    2      2
    2      3
```

But I want something that takes the lowest value and starts incrementing it and changes the value of the unique so it does not have any jumps. Is this possible to achieve?

```
    Sno Unique  Something
    1      1   new data
    1      2   new data
    1      3   somedata
    2      1
    2      2
    2      3
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest answer would be you can't do what you want if the `Unique_NO` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field because it generates 1 more the last inserted value (*even if it's already deleted*).

The best way you can do is to create a logic in your application layer that generates `Unique_No`.